# how to show the bot counter for a guild discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a bot counter in discord.js.

For example when I type: "**!bots**", the bot will send a message like: "**There are 11 bots on this server**"

I previously tried this code, but it seams to give me just the number of bots that are in cache, not all of them:

```
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the fetch() method on the members property to retrieve an array of all the members in the Discord server. You can then filter or otherwise loop through the array to check if a member is a bot.

Check the docs about it here: `https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch`

As explained by @Bqre in the comment below, this is probably not ideal though.

Comment: Highly recommend to not use this kind of method. It can very easily get you rate limited and soon enough would be considered as API abuse if used in larger servers. While it's not great, using `cache` is the best way to go about it. Most people on Discord are cached nowadays as well.

Comment: The question asked how you can retrieve non-cache'd users. I responded with what is available in the official API documentation. Whether this is the best way of doing it or not isn't what the question is about. While the response is good and clarifies on how it can be abused, it doesn't make my answer any less valid, so I don't think the downvote is fair.

Comment: Even if ethical or not the description does not fully describe a proper answer. It would be better if you explained that each member have to be fetched before being filtered. Not "I think you need to use the fetch() method..."

Comment: Fair point. Did some editing for what it's worth.

Comment: Ya, thank you, not exactly what I was looking for, but thank you!